# How to create a record which tied to has_many through with condition using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In a model, I have has_many relationship as below :

```
has_many :commercial_evaluators, -> { where("evaluators.type = 'commercial'")}, through: :evaluators, source: :user
```

In view I'm using simple form as below :

```
= f.association :commercial_evaluators,  collection: User.staff, label_method: :email
```

and the form submitted as expected :

```
"commercial_evaluator_ids"=>["", "11", "13"]
```

but it will only create like normal has many through association without the condition.

[image]

I have used cocoon gem which allows nested fields and I know it will work. But is there any simpler way for this solution?

Comment: the condition you have there is used while reading the association and not while saving the association

Comment: @emaillenin I thought it will work during writing too. hmm

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, those scopes on associations are used when "reading" the records and not while "writing" them.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

Extend your model Evaluator to CommercialEvaluator.

```
class CommercialEvaluator < Evaluator
end
```

Then in model where you desire relationship use.

```
has_many :commercial_evaluators, source: :user
```